# C Arrays and unbroken lists

Tags: c, arrays

/edit: thanks for the help so far, however I haven't got any of the solutions to take the sample input and give the sample output. My description isn't the clearest, sorry.

I have an array composed of binary data. What I want to do is determine how long each unbroken segment of 1s or 0s is.

Say I have this data:

```
0111010001110
```

In an array `binaryArray` which I need to translate to:

```
0100110
```

stored in `nwArray` where `0` represents a narrow (less than 3 digits long) and `1` represents wide (>3 digits long). I am not concerned with the binary value but with the length of each component. I'm not sure if that explanation makes sense.

This is what I have; it doesn't work, I can see why, but I can't think of a good solution.

```
for(x=0;x<1000;x++){
    if(binaryArray[x]==binaryArray[x+1]){
        count++;
        if(count>=3){
            nwArray[y]=1;
            y++;
            count=0;
        }
    }else{
        if(barcodeArray[x]){
            nwArray[y]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example output (0100110) says that count >= 3, but your code and text says (count > 3).

Comment: Yeah, this is confusing, ill let the original poster sort out exactly what he wants.

Comment: Yes, it should be >= 3. I altered it for a simpler example but I forgot to make that change. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this do it?

```
int count = 0;
for (x=0; x<1000;x++)
{
    if (binaryArray[x] != binaryArray[x+1]) 
    {
        if (count < 3)
           nwArray[y]=0;
        else 
           nwArray[y]=1;

        y++;
        count = 0;
    }
    else
        count++;
}
```

Comment: You've forgotten to write the last element (eg. in the case that binaryArray[998] == binaryArray[999]) , but other than that it looks fine.

Comment: Possibly better to rewrite it as [x-1] ... [x] anyway.  Thanks

Comment: no problem. I just saw it because it's one of the typical errors I write (forgetting the last corner-case that is) :-)

Answer (score 3):

One problem you have is that you compare count with 3 too early.  Wait until you see a change in the bitstream.  Try a while loop until the bit flips then compare the count.

Answer (score 0):

Modified [@MikeW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607348/c-arrays-and-unbroken-lists/607398#607398):

```
int count = 0;
int nwSize = 0;    
const int ilast = SIZEOF(binaryArray) - 1;
for (int i = 0; i <= ilast; ++i)
  if (i == ilast || binaryArray[i] != binaryArray[i+1]) {
    nwArray[nwSize++] = (count > 1); /* true for '1110'; false for '110' */
    count = 0;
  }
  else
    ++count;
assert(count == 0);
```